# How to open route in a new tab using MobX State Router's RouterStore?

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

https://nareshbhatia.github.io/mobx-state-router/docs/api-router-store

Looking through their docs, I don't see any mention of how to open a route in a new tab. Does this mean that I must resort to javascript's `window.open()` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening up a new tab will unavoidably create a new history stack, so it doesn't matter how you go about opening it.

You could use `window.open()` like you alluded to, or even an `a` tag with an attribute `target` set to `_blank`:

```html
<a target="_blank" href="/a-route">Open a route in a new tab</a>
```